# Set input with runat="server" to disabled based on code behind property

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to disable an `input` with `runat="server"` attribute. This should be based on a code behind property. Here's a minimal repro of my scenario in a fresh .NET 3.5 Web Forms project:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.IsReadOnly = true;
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly { get; set; }
}
```

```
<%= IsReadOnly %>
<input value="testing" runat="server" id="myinput" disabled="<%# IsReadOnly %>"/>
```

The input is *not* rendered as disabled.

What am I doing wrong? I've tried all sorts of things to no effect, including these:

- `disabled="<%= IsReadOnly %>"`: not disabled even if `IsReadOnly = true`
- `disabled='<%= IsReadOnly ? "disabled" : "" %>'`: doesn't work when `IsReadOnly = false`
- `<%= IsReadOnly ? "disabled='disabled'" : "" %>` inside the tag: parser error

How can I disable the `input` within the aspx based on the code behind property?

Comment: Why don't you just do `myinput.Disabled = IsReadOnly` in the `Page_Load` handler? Note that you can't use `<%=` in a `runat="server"` element.

Comment: That's the workaround I'm currently using. However, because the aspx already has quite a few other similar pieces I wanted to keep *all* of it there (or, when I get back to this view in a few months, I may be at a loss on how the input is being disabled).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, a couple of things to note here:

1. `<%#` is going to work in data binding context only, so not your case
2. `<%=` is equivalent to `Response.Write`, so again not your case as it cannot manipulate server-side control properties
3. Markup is processed before `Load` is called, so your initialization might be late for what you want.

Your best bet is just to do this disabling in code behind - this is the only good way of setting properties of not data bound controls. You can do it directly in the setter, like that:

```
private bool _isReadOnly;
public bool IsReadOnly
{
    get { return _isReadOnly; }
    set
    {
        myinput.Disabled = value;
        _isReadOnly = value;
    }
}
```

And you might not need getter and thus private field after all.

Comment: Guess I was so hooked on the MVVM-dope I failed to see that my workaround was the actual solution here.

Comment: PS. Any comment on how this would change if I *were* in a data-binding context with `IsReadOnly` on my model and where `<%#` *was* available? Or should I create a new SO question for that?

Comment: @Jeroen, if you were in data bound context, like inside a grid view for example, your input controls would be inside a template of some kind, and wouldn't be available in code behind just be their IDs. In that case `Disabled=<%# IsReadOnly %>` is a proper way to go